# Is 2D configurator doable with python or JavaScript?

Tags: drag-and-drop, shopify, slots, odoo-product-configurator

So, I need help with developing a 2D configurator that would have a drag and drop feature and would also be able to allow slots customizations for items on sale on a shopify shop. The items are basically a drawer inlay and a USB stick holder. Anyone using it should also be able to choose the dimensions that suit their preference.

Can anyone help me with this?

I already got HTML, CSS and JavaScript code to get me moving but I need help with the right code for customizing the drag and drop features and the slot addition as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.